# Why cannot use list(filter(boolean,python_list)) inside __new__ while defining a class in python?

Tags: python, list, inheritance, filter, new-operator

I've realized that it's not possible to apply `list(filter(_,_))`in `__new__` while defining a class.
However it's possible either to use filter or list separately.

Console throws this error:

`TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

This does not work:

```
class test():    
   def __init__(self):     
       self.mean = [1,2,3,4]
bool_list=[True,False,True,True]     

class tracegrad_set():     
   def __new__(cls,obj,bool_list):     
       list(filter(bool_list,obj.mean))     
       obj.mean= obj.mean[:2]     
       return obj       
a=test()     
b=tracegrad_set(a,bool_list)
```

Meanwhile this

```
class test():    
   def __init__(self):     
       self.mean = [1,2,3,4]
bool_list=[True,False,True,True]     

class tracegrad_set():     
   def __new__(cls,obj,bool_list):     
       filter(bool_list,obj.mean)   
       obj.mean= obj.mean[:2]     
       return obj       
a=test()     
b=tracegrad_set(a,bool_list)
```

Or this

```
class test():    
   def __init__(self):     
       self.mean = [1,2,3,4]
bool_list=[True,False,True,True]     

class tracegrad_set():     
   def __new__(cls,obj,bool_list):     
       list(bool_list,obj.mean)   
       obj.mean= obj.mean[:2]     
       return obj       
a=test()     
b=tracegrad_set(a,bool_list)
```

Comment: What's the backtrace? Which is the line throwing the error? What if you spread the nested expressions over multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

`filter` expects as first argument either a callable, or None (to just filter out elements evaluating to false-ish); you provided there a `list` of booleans, and therefore when you did try to access results of filtering, the `TypeError` was raised. The filter tried to call something like `bool_list(obj.mean[0])`

As I can only assume, that you wanted to keep the elements of list for which the indexes in the bool list were `True`, it will be easier to achieve this using list comprehension, something like:

```
my_new_list = [value for keep, value in zip(bool_list, obj.mean) if keep]
```

Or, if you insist on using `map`/`filter`, you could use something like:

```
from operator import itemgetter
...
my_new_list = map(itemgetter(1), filter(itemgetter(0), zip(bool_list, obj.mean))
# or use lambda: t: t[<index>]
```